# Testing phase for bag of visual features

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

In the bag of visual features the steps include
 Training phase
1. Feature extraction
2. Visual vocabulary by k mean
3. Bag of visual histogram
4.Train the classifiers

Is the process still the same when you are in testing phase? For example i have a car and non car images and in my training phase i had 150 car and 150 non car in the testing phase i have 50 car and 50 non car

Does the testing phase also include the creation of visual vocabulary by k means? Can someone pls explain to me how the testing phase works in BOVF?

What i know is that you need to first extract these features from the testing phase which i had already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you test an image you need to do the following:

1. Extract features from the image
2. For each feature find the closest word from the learned vocabulary. ( For example by measuring the euclidean distance between the feature and the word).
3. Than for the new vector created from the vocabulary  use the trained classier to classify the image.

Comment: Hi. When i test a new image. Do i have to assign a label forthe new image?

Comment: No. The classier will assign a label to the image. That's e point of the classier.

Comment: Hi. Final question. How do i exactly do the number 3 step? How do i creatw this new vector?

Comment: Like I wrote in the answer: For each feature go over all the words in the vocabulary and measure the distance between them. Find the word that is closest to the feature. Fill a new indicator vector with the words you find. This indicator vector you push to the classifer.